# Variables upon submitting Paypal form

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

```
<form>
    <!--- paypal form --->
</form>
```

How to send data thru paypal when submitting?

For example:

1. Upon submitting the form with an #ID  value of "12345" 
   and after paying successfully.
2. It will return back to my site ThankYou.php

Question: how will I get the value 12345?
or can I use

```
//ThankYou.php
<?php
echo $_REQUEST["#ID"];
?>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you actually had a look at the PayPal IPN, surely it describes a method for getting custom field values? Also, when you say submitting the form with an #ID value of "12345" do you mean that it's a selector, as in `<form id='12345'..>`. You should be using the `name=` attribute.

Comment: no, i mean... `<form type="hidden" name="id" value="12345"> ` I want to get the value of "id" in the thankyou.php

Comment: This may work:
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="Id value" />

Comment: Why are you requesting `#ID` as oppose to `id`? And according to this W3 document, `<form>` doesn't have the attribute `type=hidden`, are you sure you don't mean `<input>`?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="12345">` .. ok this is it... im sorry.. so after I done paying thru paypal it will redirect me back to my website then can I get the value of user_id? like this : `$_REQUEST["user_id"]; `

Comment: $_POST['user_id']; They will post the values back to your thank you page.

Comment: @sinclairchase: Did you check the PayPal IPN documentation for that? According to https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables, the parameter `rm=` can be passed through to determine the return method, with the default being `0` which is `$_GET[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal allows you to post custom values. You should be able to put a hidden form field value on your form that will make the trip back on return. Their documentation has all that information.

This may work:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="Id value" />
```

Comment: How about when I finish process the payment? How do I get the value of `name=id` I try to use `$_REQUEST['id']` but doesn't work? im such a noob ;/

Comment: You'll just use $_POST['user_id'] to get the value on your thank you page. The user_id key in the $_POST array above corresponds to your input name attribute.

Comment: Will this be a valid code.. if I print the value of user_id like this: `echo $_POST["user_id"];`? Thanks!

Comment: sinclairchase: incorrect. Only custom data in 'custom' (and other recognized parameters) is returned. Any other added data is ignored. So use <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="user ID goes here">. This will be returned in $_POST['custom']  once PayPal's IPN POST hits your server.

Comment: @Robert - Thanks. Didn't exactly remember how it worked, just knew you could do it. Why I put may instead of will.