# Paypal Hidden variables doesn't work

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variables upon submitting Paypal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578242/variables-upon-submitting-paypal-form)

```
//Buy.php
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="EWE57TOG6A1GO">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="12345">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
</form>
```

After the successful payment.
You'll be redirected to

`www.thankyou.com/thankyou.phptx=2TB90771KK039521H&st=Completed&amt=1.00&cc=PHP&cm=&item_number=11`

```
//Thankyou.php
<?php
    extract($_REQUEST);
    echo $user_id;
?>
```

I am trying to print the user_id but it is empty.

So my Question is:

1) How can I send variable from my site to paypal? (talking about the user_id)

2) How to get the value of that user_id when redirected to thankyou.php?

Thanks in ADVANCE!

Comment: Are you able to get other variables posted by hidden fields

Comment: No... I don't get any variables/value from hidden fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It worked for me when I implemented PayPal.

```
<?php

    $user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];    
    echo $user_id;    

?>
```

Slight edit: The array parameter should be in quotes and the double quotes are unnecessary in the echo statement.