# PayPal POST variables not working (PHP)

Tags: php, post, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am attempting to set up a PayPal 'subscription' payment button on a site I'm working on. It's a form that gets sent to PayPal and then sends the user back to a return URL when the transaction is successfully completed. I'm currently using the PayPal Sandbox to test this. The problem is that the POST variables are not being sent to the thank you page (which is a PHP page FYI).

The reason I need this is that I'm updating a database and if a user successfully completes a transaction, it needs to take a look at the variables being returned, determine that the user paid and then update the user's information in the MySQL database automatically.

I've been in touch with a PayPal rep for the past two weeks and they can't seem to help. I've also researched all over the web and Stack Overflow and none of the current answers seem to address my issue. Here's what I've tried:

- I started by trying to use GET variables (like  but GET variables are not supported in this way. It caused the return URL to have a crazy string of variables returned on the end of it and not my ID variable (it was like a charset and something else). The PayPal rep explained that the variables I needed to use are POST variables.
- I've set up the pages on three different servers/hosting packages to see if the host was the issue. The three I've used are GoDaddy, JustHost and 123-reg (UK). None work. I assumed the hosts would be fine since PayPal is so ubiquitous but I double checked to be sure. I know that the .htaccess file isn't preventing POST variables from working because I've used the PHP mail function from a form on this site already so that all works.
- I tried $_REQUEST variables instead of $_POST variables as suggested here: [Paypal Hidden variables doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579908/paypal-hidden-variables-doesnt-work)

Here is the code being used on the two pages. Feel free to go to these pages as well to test out the issue yourself and see that is doesn't work:

### Page

http://www.miller-media.com/sites/paypal_test/test_form.php

### Code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal_form" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Monthly Subscription">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="mbizz@paypal.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="7.00">
        <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
        <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="20130731 it worked">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.miller-media.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.miller-media.com/sites/paypal_test/mmiller.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the return URL

### Page

http://www.miller-media.com/sites/paypal_test/mmiller.php

### Code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    TEST FOR MILLER MEDIA

    THIS IS FOR POST 
    <?php
        echo ("Custom = " . $_POST['custom']);
        echo ("Transaction = " . $_POST['txn_id']);
        echo ("First name = " . $_POST['first_name']);
        echo ("Last name = ". $_POST['last_name']);
    ?>


</body>
</html>
```

This code above is what was provided by the PayPal rep to me (mine was slightly different when I first set it up). If you go through the process (with a PayPal sandbox account), no variables will show up on the thank you page (mmiller.php).

Here is a message that the PayPal rep provided to me and it showed that he get variables working correctly. It looks like he was testing locally, so I'm not sure if that had something to do with it:

```
Here is the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/zno0UkK.jpg . But I just noticed I was using a Buy Now button but your button is a subscription.

The txn_id is not returned for subscription (that is by design) . Please see below for variables that are returned. https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables#id091EB0901HT

This is what I get with subscription signup http://i.imgur.com/BOrw1Hn.jpg . A txn_id is not returned.

Here is also the complete POST data :

POSTDATA=txn_type=subscr_signup&subscr_id=I-0RSGVWA904CF&last_name=Connor&residence_country=GB&mc_currency=USD&item_name=StormAware+Monthly+Subscription&business=mbizz%40paypal.com&amount3=7.00&recurring=1&address_street=1+Main+Terrace&payer_status=verified&payer_email=UKrealPro%40paypal.com&address_status=confirmed&first_name=John&receiver_email=mbizz%40paypal.com&address_country_code=GB&payer_id=UXPBYWUW8ZDHA&address_city=Wolverhampton&reattempt=1&payer_business_name=John+Connor%27s+Test+Store&address_state=West+Midlands&subscr_date=16%3A37%3A38+Aug+05%2C+2013+PDT&address_zip=W12+4LQ&custom=20130731+it+worked&charset=windows-1252&period3=1+M&address_country=United+Kingdom&mc_amount3=7.00&address_name=John+Connor%27s+Test+Store&auth=AOgsYFMneBuxymkc0UoZ6OI6D-BXCQmWRz5xyilJR1-7uCvNI1kB Om1eHPbogzB7YnoOUIAZZiFOrx0ZcUgN-gQ&form_charset=UTF-8
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has frustrated me for the past several weeks. Thank you in advance!

Comment: the transaction details go to the IPN pages, not the return page.

Comment: Is the IPN page a variable that's set in the HTML form? The PayPal rep hasn't even mentioned IPN so I'm not sure if it's required?

Comment: you should read up on IPN its a n important part of the process

Comment: I am. I'm just wondering how the rep was able to get the variables to post successfully on his screenshots without using IPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want POST data included with your return page you'll need to setup PDT (payment data transfer.)

This is not recommended for updating databases or anything that you need to make sure happens, though, because even with Auto-Return enabled there is no guarantee the user will actually make it back to your site and you will undoubtedly end up with transactions that don't get updated correct.

That is why IPN is recommended instead.  IPN will be triggered regardless of whether or not the user makes it back to your site.

Keep your thank you page simple and do all of your post-payment processing within IPN.

Comment: Great, thank you. I've looked up IPN and sent the data to the notify_url parameter in the HTML form. It seems to work fine although there is a little bit of a lag (it's not an immediate update; sometimes it takes a minute or two). I've read that the lag is just part of the system so we'll work with it. Thanks Andrew!